# Installing numpy with pip on windows 10 for python 3.7

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7

I installed python 3.7 on my Windows 10 laptop since it has been officially released as of today (06/28/2018). Then i tried to install numpy package using pip

```
pip install numpy
```

The install proceeds but finally fails with the below error :

```
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\pcheg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7wjkw5wn\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\pcheg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-uhj8233f\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\pcheg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7wjkw5wn\numpy\
```

Any ideas as to how to overcome this install Error? Thanks.

Comment: For those trying to install numpy (or other packages that require compilation) on Python 3.9: Python 3.9 is *just out* and Numpy has not yet built wheels yet for 3.9. Don't despair, Christoph Gohlke has you covered, see the accepted answer here.

Comment: adding related link: (using apt) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225826/unable-to-install-numpy/64226324#64226324

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Installing NumPy on Windows is a common problem if you don't have the right build setup.   Instead, I always go to [Christoph Gohlke's website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs) to download the wheels you can install for your computer.  Christoph generously builds the libraries himself with the right build environment and he posts it on his website.

---

## Newer Instructions - For older instructions, please scroll down

First, install [`pipwin`](https://pypi.org/project/pipwin/) from PyPI which will install a utility that acts like `pip` but it will download the actual package you're interested in from his website, then use `pipwin install` to install the package you want.

First do:

`pip install pipwin`

When that's installed, you can then do:

`pipwin install numpy`

This will install the latest version of NumPy on your system.  This way you don't have to specifically search for the version of NumPy that is for your specific version of Python.

---

## Older instructions

Go to the NumPy section: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) then download the version for 3.7 that is compatible with your version of Python (2 or 3 and 32-bit or 64-bit).  For example, the filename `numpy‑1.14.5+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` is for NumPy 1.14.5, Python 3.7 - 64 bit.  You can pick out which version of NumPy and which version of the Python interpreter and bit version you need in the filename.

Doing this never requires you to build NumPy yourself or install the required compiler as opposed to installing NumPy through PyPI.  You can just download the wheel and install it yourself.  Assuming you've already downloaded it, just do:

```
pip install numpy‑1.14.5+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

... assuming the wheel is in the directory you're currently in.

Comment: This is the official unofficial numpy installation guide!

Answer (score 5):

## **Starting 24 November 2021, latest numpy require at least Python 3.8**

Note: This might not be the original question asked, but it might help anyone come here.

To use python 3.7, latest numpy you can use is v1.21.4. So, to install it, use:

```bash
pip install numpy==1.21.4
```

If you write requirements that you hope compatible with python 3.7, you can use `numpy<=1.21.4`

---

## **EDIT: in 20 December 2021, numpy release version 1.21.5 that support Python 3.7**

From comment section, by @sam, numpy 1.21.5 support Python 3.7. It was released after 1.22.0rc1 (the latest numpy version as the writing of the original post) that only support Python 3.8++.

Lesson learned from this experience, it would be better to use `<`,

```bash
pip install numpy<1.22.0
```

or

```py
install_requires = [
    "numpy<1.22.0", # lates version to support python 3.7
],
```

---

EDIT: `1.21.6` released on Apr 12, 2022.

Comment: note that 1.21.5 also supports Python 3.7, see https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.21.5-notes.html

Comment: @SamMason Wow, that was released after this answer. Updated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**For windows when you install a package you type in Python 3:**

```
py -m pip install [packagename]

         OR

py -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: As of October 2019 this is the much simpler solution which does not require manually selecting and downloading numpy packages. Besides, since Python now ships with `pip`, a call to install `pip` via Python is preferrable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a C compiler. If numpy doesn't provide a prebuilt wheel yet, you'll need to install a compiler. [This](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F) website shows the one you need to install. For 3.7, I assume it's still 14.0, so you should install [Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks ,I shall try it once i am home.Outside right now.  Also i did not have have any issues installing the numpy on python 3.6.6 . Just a FYI.

Comment: Exactly, because numpy provides wheel files (precompiled packages) for python 3.6 which can be installed without having a compiler.

Comment: So i installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 (15.7.4)  and then tried again to install numpy using pip  but got the same error as above .  What worked for me is rayryeng's  solution . I am guessing numpy still isn't ready yet to be installed with all needed components via pip  for python 3.7.