# "Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

This is the screenshot of my environment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpbiE.png)

I'm trying to use pandas, however I got this error:

["Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wemxh.png)

I've tried to install and uninstall pandas, as well as numpy. If someone could help, many thanks.

Comment: In Pycharm, when you go to `File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter`, do you see Pandas and Numpy in the list of packages?

Also, try to copy/paste the error message rather than posting an image. It's easier for people who try to help you :)

Comment: yes, when i see the list of packages, i see pandas and numpy package.

Comment: Could you indicate the versions of pandas and numpy you see? And add a screenshot of the package list in the Project Interpreted tab of the settings?

Comment: Pandas version:0.23.4 e numpy version:1.15.4

Comment: Also, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087158/installing-numpy-with-pip-on-windows-10-for-python-3-7

Comment: Thanks @Eskapp this worked for me.