# Unable to install Numpy

Tags: python, windows, installation, python-3.9

I'm unable to install NumPy.
I'm getting the following error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

My python version is 3.9.0

Comment: What command did you try when doing this?  pip?  apt?   what os?

Comment: pip install numpy

Comment: Can you try apt-get install python3-numpy or apt-get install numpy ?  or,  pip3 install numpy ? (Or something on those lines)  The problem you're facing is similar to a problem I faced awhile ago.

Comment: You are a genius....worked with pip3 install numpy...Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Oh,  very well!  posting it as answer, Would you mark it as solution? thanks!  I am still new, so it would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:   Nice it worked for you:

pip3 install numpy

If it, for some reason - for someone in the future wouldn't work in some way:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3

sudo apt install pip pip3 
sudo apt install python3 python-numpy python3-numpy

pip install numpy
pip3 install numpy
```

Depending on which version you want.

Hope this can be useful for someone in the future!

Edit2:
Orpheus comment:

> pipwin needs to be installed for installing numpy, pip install pipwin
> and then pipwin install numpy – Orpheus

Regards.

Comment: Can you add that pipwin needs to be installed for installing numpy, pip install pipwin and then pipwin install numpy

Comment: @Orpheus Of course!