# Some problems with numpy install

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-3.9

When I try to install numpy with `pip install numpy` with *Python 3.9* I got this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c: 'c:prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C
         cwd:
    Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
```

I watched a lot of tutorials and search some similar problems on stackoverflow, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: *I watched a lot of tutorials and search some similar problems on stackoverflow, but I can't find an answer.* - No, there are a few: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091218/12983399 for instance. If instructions seem complicated or like an overkill, just install an older version of Python and stuff should work fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install new packages for Python (Python 3.9.0, Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323080/cant-install-new-packages-for-python-python-3-9-0-windows-10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing numpy with pip on windows 10 for python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087158/installing-numpy-with-pip-on-windows-10-for-python-3-7)

Comment: i need version 3.9 for school

Comment: I appreciate for the reputation on '-', but can you still help me solve the problem if you still tell me it's dubbed?

Comment: There are no prebuilt `numpy` wheels for Python 3.9 out there yet. If you have to install `numpy` for Python 3.9, you have to build it from source. This is anything but trivial for a newcomer; you'll need to install and configure C and FORTRAN compilers on Windows, LAPACK and BLAS libraries and some build-time dependencies like Cython. Here are the [instructions for building from source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html). Better ask your teacher first if Python 3.9 is indeed required.

Comment: I managed to install it. I used `pip install pipwin` and with pipwin I installed numpy with `pipwin install numpy`